# Unity Game View text shows up as blocks locally

Tags: unity-game-engine

Blocky Game View using unity to make a phone app. All of my Objects in the scene show up properly, but show up in game view as colored blocks. Other people working on the project do not have this problem, so the issue is local. I think I must have missed a setting or something.

[image]

Comment: please show a picture of the problem. it is hard to tell like that.

Comment: I added the image of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the scale (x28) is messing your resolution.
try to adjust the scale and the regulation your are working on.
It seems you set 10X16 fixed resoultion.